# How to Format a String

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-8, formatting, format

In my app I am determining network changes as they occur. I have some sample code that I was using but I would like to format the resulting string in a certain manner

```
string change = string.Empty;
        switch (e.NotificationType)
        {
            case NetworkNotificationType.InterfaceConnected:
                change = "Connected to ";
                break;
            case NetworkNotificationType.InterfaceDisconnected:
                change = "Disconnected from ";
                break;
            case NetworkNotificationType.CharacteristicUpdate:
                change = "Characteristics changed for ";
                break;
            default:
                change = "Unknown change with ";
                break;
        }

        string changeInformation = String.Format(" {0} {1} {2} ({3})",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString(), change, e.NetworkInterface.InterfaceName,
                    e.NetworkInterface.InterfaceType.ToString());

        // We are making UI updates, so make sure these happen on the UI thread.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            Changes.Add(changeInformation); //Changes contains the changeInformation
        });
```

Currently the result looks like

[image]

but this is not formatted well at all, and tends to get jumbled at times. I'd like to be able to format it so that `DateTime.Now.ToString()` is on the top line, then the `change` on the next line, followed by `e.NetworkInterface.InterfaceName` and `e.NetworkInterface.InterfaceType.ToString()`. How could I do this?

Comment: use linebreaks... (\n helps)

Comment: `String.Format(" {0}\n{1}\n{2} ({3})", ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either explicit `\r\n` or better still, `Environment.NewLine`, e.g.

```
String.Format(" {0}{1}{2}{3}{4}({5})",
                DateTime.Now, Environment.NewLine, 
                change, Environment.NewLine, 
                e.NetworkInterface.InterfaceName,
                e.NetworkInterface.InterfaceType);
```

Note also that you don't need a naked `.ToString()` in the parameters - this is implied in `String.Format()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add new line

```
string changeInformation = String.Format(" {0} {1} {2} {3} ({4})",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString(), Environment.NewLine, change, e.NetworkInterface.InterfaceName,
                    e.NetworkInterface.InterfaceType.ToString());
```